# Highcharts: Is it possible to have separate plotOptions for each series?

Tags: highcharts

I want to have two scatter series on my chart. One with a linewidth of 1 and the other with no lineWidth. As I understand, the plotOptions applies to all charts of the specified type, so either all the scatter plots have a linewidth or nothing. Is it possible to apply a plotOptions to specific series?

Comment: You should mark @Igor Dymov's answer as the right one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> In addition to the members listed below, any member of the plotOptions for that specific type of plot can be added to a series individually. For example, even though a general lineWidth is specified in plotOptions.series, an individual lineWidth can be specified for each series.

Just pass `lineWidth` to `series` as a parameter like:

```
var series = {
    data: [...],
    lineWidth: 1
};
```

Comment: i just confused with [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258753/highchart-scatter-point-not-connected)