# "Guide lines" in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I need to draw percentile curves on my graphs so that people can interpret the actual data compared to the "standards". Obviously, since those curves only serve as an aid, they need to be "non interactive".

I've been messing around with hover and marker options and other things, but get nowhere to what I want (for one, the line hover refuses to disable). Does anyone have pointers or an example on how to do this?

What I'm trying to get to is like this (but only for one set of measurements per graph):

[image: Percentile curves for growth]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case simply set: `enableMouseTracking: false`, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.enableMouseTracking).

Comment: Indeed, I've found the solution myself by now when i stumbled on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616409/highcharts-is-it-possible-to-have-separate-plotoptions-for-each-series/6623843 - It was very unclear to me that the plotOptions.line could also be applied to individual series. I also disabled the markers for those series and it does what I want now. Since you replied before I could answer my own question, the rep goes to you. Thanks :)

Comment: Sure, anyway, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/KTeJU/ (separate options for each series).

Comment: Indeed. And when you disable markers and add lineWidth to it you get pretty much what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/Blizzke/uxUnL/1/ :)