# Highchart scatter point not connected

Tags: highcharts

I set the `lineWidth` already to let every point connected to each other but it's still won't work. Please help me to inspect the sample data below and also the options setting

```
[{"x":101.4,"y":69.235,"marker":{"fillColor":"#BF0B23"}},{"x":101.23,"y":69.24},{"x":101.03,"y":69.24},{"x":100.82,"y":69.22},{"x":100.61,"y":69.21},{"x":100.41,"y":69.21},{"x":99.95,"y":69.19},{"x":99.96,"y":69.19},{"x":100,"y":69.14},{"x":100.03,"y":69.1},{"x":100.04,"y":69.1},{"x":100.09,"y":69.085},{"x":100.15,"y":69.08},{"x":100.08,"y":69.135},{"x":100.03,"y":69.095},{"x":100.06,"y":69.07},{"x":100.1,"y":69.07},{"x":100.25,"y":69.045},{"x":100.18,"y":69.105},{"x":102.82,"y":68.925},{"x":102.52,"y":68.89},{"x":102.2,"y":68.86},{"x":102.18,"y":68.87},{"x":102.25,"y":68.855},{"x":102.21,"y":68.845},{"x":102.82,"y":69.595},{"x":102.9,"y":69.575},{"x":102.86,"y":69.595},{"x":102.8,"y":69.775},{"x":102.83,"y":69.695},{"x":102.83,"y":69.755},{"x":102.82,"y":69.615},{"x":102.91,"y":69.615},{"x":102.88,"y":69.575},{"x":102.98,"y":69.585},{"x":103.16,"y":69.655},{"x":103,"y":69.655},{"x":102.91,"y":69.595},{"x":102.82,"y":69.595},{"x":102.7,"y":69.575},{"x":102.76,"y":69.625},{"x":102.77,"y":69.575},{"x":102.76,"y":69.545},{"x":102.85,"y":69.505},{"x":102.99,"y":69.505},{"x":103.02,"y":69.505},{"x":102.88,"y":69.515},{"x":103,"y":69.845},{"x":103.19,"y":69.805},{"x":103.1,"y":69.725},{"x":102.79,"y":69.675},{"x":102.96,"y":69.735},{"x":103.14,"y":69.625},{"x":103.02,"y":69.615},{"x":103.27,"y":69.785},{"x":103.19,"y":69.765},{"x":102.88,"y":69.475},{"x":103,"y":69.475},{"x":102.99,"y":69.395},{"x":99.49,"y":69.195},{"x":99.32,"y":69.215,"marker":{"fillColor":"black"}}]
```

this is not the whole data. The data is not fit in in SO `textarea`

**the options**

```
options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        animation:false             
    },              
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            turboThreshold: 9999
        }                   
    },              
    series: [{
        name: 'Hysteresis',
        data: [],
        lineWidth: 2
    }]
}
```

Here my attempt to use with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77vmqrv7/4/) and it's working. But for your information, I dynamically load the data like this `chart.series[0].setData()` and it's not working

**screenshot of `console.log($('ele').highcharts());`**

[image]

[image]

this is the alternative that I tried, how I push the data to the series before initiated highcharts

```
options.series[0].data.push({
    x: parseFloat(model.get('xreading')), 
    y: parseFloat(model.get('yreading')), 
    marker:{ fillColor: '#BF0B23', symbol: 'triangle' }, label: model.get('iv_date')
});
```

Any possible options that might prevent it from draw the line

Comment: You should post whatever code you have working to http://jsfiddle.net so it's easier to troubleshoot it.

Comment: sorry i'm not that good with jsfiddle. I'll try it next time

Comment: For me line is printed. http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/bd5t4oaa/, update my example with your code, which doesnt work.

Comment: Using the setData() method as you describe, it is working for me as well: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/77vmqrv7/5/

Comment: do you have any idea what is possible settings/options that might prevent it from drawing the line. Mine is still not working

Comment: is there any limitation on data? I have 1363 points actually

Comment: for your information, i use backbone and generate chart as backbone.view

Comment: Please supply us live demo, then we will check what is wrong, without it its not possible. Because our examples works properly.

Comment: it's offline application, and since it's made of backbone not sure how to construct it back. My part is generate graph only. However I upload some `console.log` screenshot if any of it helps. See my question above

Comment: Any errors in console? Maybe you have set color with 100% of opacity? Also, do you have 4+ version of Highcharts?

Comment: i used 4.0.3 version. just updated just now. No errors at all

Comment: i have update the question. See how I push data to the series

Comment: any idea on `JSON`? Might have incompatible format or element

Comment: In the optiosn part, you use it in any loop, to push each point from json ?

Comment: yes. is there anything wrong?

Comment: hi, any idea what's wrong with push data in loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve this little problem when it is not connected,

- check your data. Make sure x and y is available if normal push array
- not working for you, why not you try build json string then later parse it

that's all folks

Answer (score -1):

A scatter plot ([definition of a scatter plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_plot) @ Wikipedia) doesn't have lines connecting each data point.  Line graphs have lines: [Highcharts, Basic Line](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic) @ highcharts.com

Change:

```
type: 'scatter',
```

to

```
type: 'line',
```

Then change the `plotOptions` accordingly.

Maybe what you really want is a trend line?  See: https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/highcharts_trendline
That's a [regression line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) which is automatically calculated to fit your data?

Comment: i tried to read chart object on browser console. Is there any settings that we can try to look into?

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul not sure what you are asking.  If you look at the jsfiddle that Sebastian Bochan provided you will see a working example of a jsfiddle which has your data in it.  Your data doesn't look like it lends itself to a line plot.  It does look like it would do better as scatter plot, but then no lines are used.  Why do you want lines?

Comment: i need the line because there is connection between each point. I have update my question and make up a jsFiddle. And it's working that way. And @jlbriggs also has provided an example which uses `setData`. But mine is still not working.